# How should I make ForEach in SwiftUI only present the latest value

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I receive a lot of values from bluetooth which are stored in an array, so I use ForEach to print the values, but I want it to update e.g. the next value will replace the previous value and continue instead of appearing all,i.e. I only show now latest value

```
 ForEach(tests.test_Data,id: \.self) { item in
  Text("\(String(format: "%.1f",item))")
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Don't use ForEach then...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to give out the latest value its simply

```
let lastValueIndex : Int = tests.test_Data.count-1
let lastValue = tests.test_Data[lastValueIndex] //last Value of your array

Text("\(String(format: "%.1f",lastValue))")
```

Comment: Thanks your help, but I decided to stored my data in  var not array.In this way, only one data will appear finally.